# bot not running bs4 discord.py

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord.py

So i have a bot i am trying to run but when i have this code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import aiohttp

class daddy:
    """My custom cog that does stuff!"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@commands.command()
async def dottanow(self):
    """How many players are online atm?"""

    #Your code will go here
    url = "https://steamdb.info/app/570/graphs/" #build the web adress
    async with aiohttp.get(url) as response:
        soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")
    try:
        online = soupObject.find(class_='home-stats').find('li').find('strong').get_text()
        await self.bot.say(online + ' players are playing this game at the moment')
    except:
        await self.bot.say("Couldn't load amount of players. No one is playing this game anymore or there's an error.")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(daddy(bot))
```

and i don't know what the issue is, my bot doesn't do anything and it doesn't print to console, or put anything in the discord, i am sure i am not messing anything up. But if i am please let me know. i am on windows 10 using py 3.6

Comment: Are you actually loading this extension in a discord bot and running it?  Could you also fix your indentation so it's identical here to how it is in your code?

Comment: Yes i can let me fix it

Comment: Stack overflow is not letting me do it so here is a ghostbin link https://ghostbin.com/paste/od7da

Answer (score 0):

The command has to go inside the class.  In your code it is outside the class.

```
class daddy:
    """My custom cog that does stuff!"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def dottanow(self):
        ...
```

Comment: @SpecialSnwoflake The code in that link does not have `@commmands.command` et. al. indented at the same level as `def __init__`